# How to access Dynamodb from inside AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

How do you read a Dynamodb record from inside an AWS Lambda function?

I'm trying to call `get_item` via:

```
import os
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    id = event['id']
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')
    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'id': id,
        }
    )
    print('response:', response)
    item = response['Item']
    return {}
```

but when I run a test via the Lambda test tool, the it fails with the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'Item'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 33, in handler\n    item = response['Item']\n"
  ]
}
```

Even though the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.02) say `get_item` should return an object containing the `Item` dictionary, it actually returns:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'DIDH3KVSPP1LU7O0TBLGP701QRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Thu, 24 Oct 2019 03:15:42 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '2', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'DIDH3KVSPP1LU7O0TBLGP701QRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'x-amz-crc32': '2745614147'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Why is `Item` not provided? How do I retrieve a record from Dynamo?

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and it worked perfectly fine:

- First, I created a DynamoDB table with a Primary Key called `id`
- I then added a few items to the table
- I then ran your code, with changes for my table:

```py
import boto3

def handler(event, context):
    id = 'food'
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
    table = dynamodb.Table('stack')
    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'id': id,
        }
    )
    print('response:', response)
    item = response['Item']
    return {}
```

This returned:

```
response: {'Item': {'id': 'food', 'name': 'apple'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '...', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Thu, 24 Oct 2019 04:38:35 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '49', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '...', 'x-amz-crc32': '...'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Note the `Item` at the front of the returned data.

Some possible reasons why it did not work for you:

- You received a `KeyError`. Check that your primary key is called `id` to match the code in the `get_item()` call.
- The table might not have any entries with the `id` set to the value being requested. When I tried this, **I got exactly the same error message you received**. Therefore, check what your code is doing with `id = event['id']`, since it probably isn't returning the value you are expecting.